# On click event on iframe by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have following html code

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/fosweb/service/lead/photos/shuffle?batchId=Cars_13164926417723&agentId=9">

</iframe>
```

js code is

```
$(function(){
$('iframe').load(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.idPhotosOnly li a', function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
    });
```

When we are clicking on that a tag, it have to get attributes

Comment: I have integrating external path only

Comment: check your browser console, also please assure you are not getting this error in console: `Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument`.

Comment: The page is loading in jsfiddle. I have checked. but event is not initiated